# Indentation shortcuts in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, delphi, indentation

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and C#. How can I indent the selected text to left/right by using shortcuts?

[image]

In the Delphi IDE the equivalents are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: CTRL+K and after CTRL+D?

Comment: I got 5 good answers in the same time...which one to accept? +1 for all the answers. thank you

Comment: Note that the newer versions of Delphi also use [tab] and [shift][tab] keys, but still support the old indent/unindent block commands

Comment: just by removing and re-adding the last curly brace, VS2010 will auto-indent the code block for you

Answer (score 306, accepted):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will do that.

Another cool trick is holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd> when you select text, it will allow you to make a square selection.  Starting with VS2010, you can start typing and it will replace the contents of your square selection with what you type.  Absolutely awesome for changing a bunch of lines at once.

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean about the VS2010 feature, but that kind of sounds like SyncEdit, which Delphi has had for years and years now.

Comment: @Mason It's nowhere near as powerful and SyncEdit. It allows you to make a rectangular selection. So if the selection covers multiple lines it does not need to cover multiple columns. Then when you type you replace each line with what you type. So your variables have to be aligned vertically for it to be any use. This is one area where RAD Studio wins hands down.

Comment: FYI, Tab and Shift+Tab also work under Delphi XE2, (as does the ALT 'trick') although in earlier versions it will just replace your selection with a tab character.

Comment: tab & shift+tab works for indenting Python code in Visual Code Code 1.11.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 and onwards theres Edit > Format Selection (Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F) which formats the current selection.

Answer (score 145):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>
>
> Will just prettify the entire document. Saves a lot of messing about,
>   compared to delphi.

Make sure to remove all indents by first selecting everything with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> 
repeatedly until everything is aligned to the left. After you do that 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> 
will work the way you want them to.

You could also do the same but only to a selection of code by highlighting the block of code you want to realign, aligning it to the left side
(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and then after making sure you've selected the code you want to realign press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> **or** just right click the highlighted code and select "Format Selection".

Comment: Ctrl-K-D does format the entire document. There is another shortcut for formatting the selected text (Ctrl-K-F maybe?).

Comment: there are also in Delphi free 3d party tools which can do that and can be integrated in the IDE.

Comment: Aye looked at them. Would change every file in 15 years of source code, not to mention a big fight over how the code should be indented. BeyondCompare would have a fit. :(

Comment: @RBA - or built in the latest versions (as well as the [TAB] handling)

Comment: @Tony, Delphi now has a built-in code formatter (for a few versions now) that you can customize to suit almost any style. There have been free, open source IDE add-ins for years that also can be customized to work with almost any formatting you want. The "compared to Delphi" portion of your answer is therefore wrong. Not downvotin' - just sayin'. :)

Comment: Stuck on Delphi 2005. :( Don't ask!. Besides even if I had one, 15 years, 5 companies, 50+ developers and 3189 management coding standards later. Not happening..

Comment: Please remove the ctrl-k+ctrl-d shortcut... the question is about a selection of text not the entire document. I just prettified my entire source file and it took 45 minutes of hunk discarding in sourcetree to remove the unwanted changes from the file for commit.

Answer (score 46):

If you would like nicely auto-formatted code. Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. While holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> hit <kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>k</kbd>, then <kbd>f</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl-D (format document) is a better shortcut as it does the same thing ( Ctrl-A selects the whole document, then K + F formats the selection )

Comment: @Raghurocks: What James meant was Ctrl+K+D, presumably, which formats the entire document.

Comment: Thank you. Although `a` is optional.

Comment: CTRL K + F to format the selected code
CTRL A + K + F, means CTRL A select all, then format  the selected code, means all

Comment: [Ctrl]+[K],[Ctrl]+[D] is what does it for me. The way I remember is because Kevin Durant is a great basketball player. I always say "Kevin Durant will fix the formatting for me."

Answer (score 30):

Tab to tab right, shift-tab to tab left.

Answer (score 19):

Visual studio’s smart indenting does automatically indenting, but we can select a block or all the code for indentation.

1. Select all the code: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
2. Use either of the two ways to indentation the code:

   - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>,
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

Answer (score 17):

You can just use `Tab` and `Shift+Tab`

Answer (score 7):

Just hit Tab to push it over or on the menu bar Edit --> Advanced --> Format Selection and that will auto indent, the keyboard shortcut is also shown in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

If the move-left and move-right shortcuts do not appear on your screen, click at the rightmost position of your toolbar at the top.  You should get "Add or Remove Buttons."  Add the buttons "decrease line indent" and "increase line indent"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly select the text you want to edit(indent), then press `Tab` to see the snippet move towards the right.